# Error when checking out (Netbeans 7.4 and Subversion 1.8.10.42400)

Tags: svn, netbeans, repository

I've found some threads related to the subject but nothing seems to work for me.

When I click on Team->Subversion->Checkout, select my repository URL (file:///var/svn/repos) I get the following:

svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///var/svn/repos'

svn: E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '5'; found format '6'

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that your repository was created with Subversion 1.8, but Netbeans is using 1.7. You probably have multiple versions of Subversion installed and are using the older one from within Netbeans. Find the older one and remove it, or point Netbeans at the newer client.

There are two ways to prevent this from happening in the future:

1. Make sure all SVN clients on a given system are at matching versions
2. Use a proper Subversion server, instead of the `file:///` protocol.

I recommend both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer and recommendations. I will install it on a proper server later on.

Still having the problem, though. I have checked everywhere and 1.8 seems to be the only version I have. Also, as far as I know, NetBeans is linked correctly to the repository from 1.8. I've deleted subversion and created a new repository folder, but no luck.

Is there somewhere specific for me to check it?

Thank you.